# Snapcraft unknown plugin "make-project"

Tags: snap, dotnet

When I run Snapcraft with [this](https://github.com/tomconte/dnxsnap) project I get this error :

"Issue while loading plugin: unknown plugin: make-project"

I have changed `dnu` to `dotnet` in the makefile.

Here is my changed snapcraft.yaml file :

```
name: dnx-sample
version: 1.0
summary: .NET Core example Snap
description: test

parts:
  dnxsample:
    plugin: make-project
    source: dnxhelloworld
    stage-packages:
      - libunwind8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `snapcraft list-plugins` to list plugins. "make-project" isn't a valid one, but "make" is. So you need:-

`plugin: make`